# In Pathfinder, does the free Trip from Hammer to the Ground also provoke?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, feats, combat-maneuver

Normally, when using Bull Rush you provoke an attack of opportunity from your target.  [Hammer to the Ground](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/dwarf/foehammer-fighter-dwarf) lets you make a Trip combat manuver after a successful Bull Rush.  Will that trip also provoke?  What if you take the option to attempt the trip without moving with your opponent?  You take the -5 to trip, but does the enemy still get an attack of opportunity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both the bull rush and the trip attempt, unless you have improved bull rush and/or improved trip, will provoke attacks of opportunity.  The general rule of provoking always applies, unless there is a specific exception.  Since **Hammer to the Ground** doesn't make a specific exception, it is safe to assume the general rule about combat maneuvers provoking attacks of opportunity still applies.